# Strange error when use hive udf through jdbc client

Tags: jdbc, hadoop, hive, hiveql

all. I met a strange error when I use hive udf through jdbc client.

I have a udf to help me convert a string into time stamp format called `reformat_date`. I firstly execute `ADD JAR` and `CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION`, both work fine.

The SQL also can be explained in hive cli mode, and can be executed. But when use jdbc client, I got errors:

```
    Query returned non-zero code: 10, cause: 
    FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line 1:283 Wrong arguments ''20121201000000'': 
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: 
    Unable to execute method public org.apache.hadoop.io.Text com.aa.datawarehouse.hive.udf.ReformatDate.evaluate(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text)  on object com.aa.datawarehouse.hive.udf.ReformatDate@4557e3e8 of class com.aa.datawarehouse.hive.udf.ReformatDate with arguments {20121201000000:org.apache.hadoop.io.Text} of size 1: 
    at com.aa.statistic.dal.impl.TjLoginDalImpl.selectAwakenedUserCount(TjLoginDalImpl.java:258)
    at com.aa.statistic.backtask.service.impl.UserBehaviorAnalysisServiceImpl.recordAwakenedUser(UserBehaviorAnalysisServiceImpl.java:326)
    at com.aa.statistic.backtask.controller.BackstatisticController$21.execute(BackstatisticController.java:773)
    at com.aa.statistic.backtask.controller.BackstatisticController$DailyExecutor.execute(BackstatisticController.java:823)
```

My SQL is

```
select count(distinct a.user_id) as cnt from ( select user_id, user_kind, login_date, login_time from tj_login_hive where p_month = '2012_12' and login_date = '20121201' and user_kind = '0' ) a join ( select user_id from tj_login_hive where p_month <= '2012_12' and datediff(to_date(reformat_date(concat('20121201', '000000'))), to_date(reformat_date(concat(login_date, '000000')))) >= 90 ) b on a.user_id = b.user_id
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think your udf threw exception. 
if `reformat_date` function is that you make, you should check your logic.
if not, you should check the udf's specification.

Comment: `reformat_date` is my udf. I can use it in the hive shell, but I can't use it through java JDBC client.